# Swipe up to show button in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8, uicollectionview

I'd like to place a button at the top of a UITableView or UICollectionView, but only shown when swiped up beyond the first row. Usually you see `scroll to refresh` or a `search bar` there, but I'd like to put a button there for another functionality. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the button on your first row and the rest of the data after. Set an inset on the tableview so the first row is hidden until the user scrolls.